# WebSocket handshake response missing HTTP status line

Tags: kotlin, websocket, tcp, rfc6455

Due to an interest in the subject, I've decided to have a go at making a WebSocket client library for Kotlin using TCP.

So, I'm reading RFC6455 and it mentions that in the handshake, the server response should have a HTTP status line. Cool, I make my request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: echo.websocket.org:80
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Accept: */*
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Dg8CY18ZTGbAkIzNhpO3mA==
```

and the server replies with

```
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: akyZ/0pr8WyuXVfejRWVAUGSW3k=
Upgrade: websocket
```

As you can see, no HTTP status line. Did I miss something in RFC6455, is my code dumb?

code (PayloadFactory.kt):

```kotlin
fun createSecWebSocketKey(): String? {
    val bytes = ByteArray(16)
    SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(bytes)
    return String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes)!!)
}

fun createOpeningHandshake(host: String, path: String = "/", port: Int = 80, protocolVersion: Int = 13): String
{
    // I'm aware path isn't used yet, that's something I plan to implement but haven't yet.
    var handshake = ""
    handshake += "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    handshake += "Host: $host:$port\r\n"
    handshake += "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
    handshake += "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
    handshake += "Accept: */*\r\n"
    handshake += "Sec-WebSocket-Version: $protocolVersion\r\n"
    handshake += "Sec-WebSocket-Key: ${createSecWebSocketKey()}\r\n\r\n"
    return handshake
}
```

code (WebSocket.kt):

```kotlin
class WebSocket(protocol: String, host: String, port: Int = 80, protocolVersion: Int = 13) {
    private val client: Socket = Socket(host, port)
    private val globallyUniqueIdentifier = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

    init {
        val handshake = createOpeningHandshake(host, protocolVersion = protocolVersion)
        println("============CLIENT HANDSHAKE============")
        println(handshake)
        client.getOutputStream().write(handshake.toByteArray())
        println("============SERVER RESPONSE=============")
        val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
        while (true)
        {
            if (input.readLine() != null) {
                val line = input.readLine()
                println(line)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to run:
`WebSocket("ws", "echo.websocket.org", 80)`

Comment: You are throwing away every odd line of the response. You need to store the result of the first `readLine()` into a variable, test it for null, and if not then display it. And not execute the second `readLine()`. And if it is null you need to exit the read loop.

Comment: user207421 you are amazing, I should've seen this myself, but thank you so much for pointing it out and solving my problem!

Comment: Not amazing at all, just experienced. The usual way to write this is `while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just an idiot. I've been coding since I was 9, I'm 17 now, I should've seen this mistake. Thank you so much! And thanks for the more efficient way of writing the loop, I appreciate it!

Comment: (Minor tips: we don't use [solved] devices in the subject line here - click the tick/check mark on your answer instead. We tend to discourage voting advice/commentary in posts - we don't think it has any effect, or it may encourage people to downvote. It is not useful to most readers anyway. Put it in the comments if you want to).

Comment: I'm not able to mark my own post as the answer, I have to wait two days, it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I was not storing the result of readLine() in a variable, causing me to essentially discard every odd line in the response. Thanks to user207421 for pointing it out!